# How to use custom template for wp page using fishpig

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way to create a custom template for specific Page (ID or Title).

Comment: This is pretty vague. More details are going to be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a custom template using xml instructions are provided by fishpig

You would just need the following in your themes local.xml file

```
<wordpress_page_view_4>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="wp.post.view">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>wordpress/page/custom_view.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_page_view_4>
```

This would set the page template to 1 column and and the wordpress view template to custom_view.phtml for a Wordpress page with an ID of 4